# Using Windows API call in Java using "native"

Tags: java, winapi, native

I've tried to solve this issue by referring possible duplicates but none of them seem to be helpful.

Here's a code that I'm using to call Win API methods in Java to get current Windows User Name, and a native Windows MessageBox, but I'm getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError` that says that my code is unable to locate the `native` method I'm trying to call.

```
public class TestNative
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long[] buffer= { 128 };
        StringBuffer username = new StringBuffer((int)buffer[0]);
        GetUserNameA(username,buffer);
        System.out.println("Current User : "+username);
        MessageBoxA(0,"UserName : "+username,"Box from Java",0);
    }
    /** @dll.import("ADVAPI32") */
    static native void GetUserNameA(StringBuffer username,long[] buffer);
    /** @dll.import("USER32") */
    private static native int MessageBoxA(int h,String txt,String title,int style);
}
```

What can be my possible (relatively simple) solution to call native Windows methods in Java. I realize that it will kill the very reason of Java being a cross-platform language, but I need to work on a project for Windows, to be developed in Java.

Thanks.

**Update**

As David Heffernan suggested, I've tried changing the method signature of `MessageBox` to `MessageBoxA`, but still it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's related to the signatures not matching completely.

The GetUserName function takes two parameters: a LPTSTR and a LPDWORD.  Java will likely not handle the StringBuffer acting as a TCHAR array for you.

Also, why bother using the Windows API for this?  Java can probably get the user's logon name (quick google says: System.getProperty("user.name")), and Swing can make a message box (even one that looks like a Windows one).

Comment: Well, getting username is not the purpose of the application I'll be developing, this is just to test whether I can call the API functions using `native` with above method or not.

Comment: Ah, I should not have assumed that was your end goal.  I still suspect that the non-exactly matching signatures are the problem.  My interest has been piqued now, so I'm going to go try it.

Comment: After googling around, unless it's a new feature, I suspect that you'll have to write wrapper code.  After looking into how JNI works, I do not think there's a way to directly call a function in a DLL without some Java-aware code in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://github.com/twall/jna. I have heard good things and its supposed to make jni that bit easier with many conveniences and simplifications.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a -Djava.library.path VM arg set with the path to your DLL's? Alternatively, you can have it in your system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because there is no MessageBox. You presumably mean MessageBoxA.

Comment: I tried changing the method signature to `MessageBoxA` but still getting same error.